# Browser can process scripts before handle post request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, restangular

Browser can process scripts before handle post request. Conside I have the following sample

```
if (some true condition) {
   console.log("ready to post")
   restangular.all.post(RequestData).then(function(response){
      //some post methods
      console.log("response")
   });       
}
//then containing scripts
cosole.log('Hello')
....
```

## output

ready to post
Hello
response

I expect to do the POST request before printing "Hello". How to overcome this?

Comment: Put the 'Hello' next to the 'response'?! The *asynchronous* execution is happening the way it is, that's the way it works, that's why there are things like `.then`...

Comment: Can you rephrase this question please? I am not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want you should look into *angularJS promises*, since the POST request is asynchronous. For example check this link:
http://www.webdeveasy.com/javascript-promises-and-angularjs-q-service/

The main idea is to first create a call that returns a *deferred* object, something like

```
this.myFunction = function (myForm) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post(myURL, myForm)
        .success(function (data) {
            //resolve the promise
            deferred.resolve('SUCCESS');
        })
        .error(function (data) {
            //reject the promise
            deferred.reject('ERROR');
        });

    //return the promise
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

and then call it like

```
    var myPromise = this.myFunction ($scope.modalForm);
    // wait until the promise return resolve or eject
    //"then" has 2 functions (resolveFunction, rejectFunction)
    myPromise.then(function(resolve){
       // do stuff here, the post request is successfully finished
    }, function(reject){
        return;
    });
```

Alternatively, any code you want to be executed after the POST request, you can put it in the *success* function of the request.